# Latte dock's dock won't appear

Tags: latte-dock

This problem appeared after uninstalling the one in the software center and installing the git version since it has many features

I have tried the replace command, restarting my computer, and deleting the contents of the config file & putting it back in

It did work on the software center version.

[image: desktop with no dock]

System info:

- OS:Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- RAM:4 gb
- CPU:intel core i3-7020U @2.30 ghz
- GPU:Intel HD 620

Answer (score 2):

OP's edit to the question indicating the solution:

> Okay, I have solved this problem by deleting the latte folder in `$HOME/.config` folder - hope this helps to anyone who encounters this problem.